# ¿Es "pincho" un equivalente de "palillo/mondadientes"?

Tags: vocabulario, sinónimos

Ayer me preguntaba mi mujer si "pincho" es un equivalente de "palillo". Yo dije que con "pincho" uno no se refiere al palillo (mondadientes) en sí, pero puede referirse a una *tapa* que use el palillo (bien para sujetar los componentes de la tapa o para facilitar el poder asir la tapa por algún lado).

Por lo visto la duda les surgió en un grupo de angloparlantes. Mi mujer habla español como segundo idioma (con gran influencia del español de España) y ella opinaba que "pincho" no es equivalente de "palillo". Sin embargo había una persona nativa de México que aseguraba que "pincho" sí es un equivalente de "palillo", cosa que no he podido corroborar.

¿Es `pincho` un equivalente de `palillo` en México u otros países de habla hispana? Yo pondría la mano en el fuego por que en España no, pero lo mismo hay regiones en las que sí tiene ese significado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Argentina un *pincho* es cualquier cosa que pinche o que se pueda pinchar, pero el uso es bastante restringido. A mí me sugiere un objeto de origen natural, sea vegetal o animal (pero las rosas y los pescados tienen *espinas*, no *pinchos*, y las cositas de madera que se le clavan a uno son *astillas*).

Al *palillo* (mondadientes de madera) se le llama *escarbadientes* (algunas personas dicen *mondadientes* pero en general nos suena tan ridículo como decir *emparedado* en vez de *sandwich*). Un palo pequeño es un *palito* (el *-illo/a* como diminutivo no se emplea).

Conocemos también el uso de *pincho* en España como comida, pero aquí no tenemos un nombre específico. Si el pincho ensarta muchas cosas (a la manera de una [banderilla](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banderilla_(tapa))) a eso le llamamos *brochettes* (pronunciado *brochet*). En Perú a esas mismas banderillas les dicen *anticuchos* y estoy seguro de que cada país de la región tiene un nombre distinto.

Answer (score 2):

Puedo dar una respuesta tentativa como hablante del español de España. La acepción de "[pincho](http://dle.rae.es/?id=T2okNU7)" que nos ocupa es la siguiente:

> 4. m. Porción de comida tomada como aperitivo, que a veces se atraviesa con un palillo.

Como ves, la propia definición distingue entre el propio *pincho* y el palillo que se usa para sujetarlo. A su vez, define "[palillo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RYenxq2%7CRaOp0rz)" como "mondadientes de madera".

Sin embargo, hay otra definición de "pincho" que me ha extrañado:

> 7. f. Espina de plantas o pescados que puede clavarse en el cuerpo.

Y lo que me extraña es que esté definido como "nombre femenino" cuando yo siempre lo he usado en masculino: *Me he clavado un pincho intentando coger el erizo de mar*; *A mi hermano se le ha clavado un pincho del cactus*.

Es decir, acabamos llamando "pincho" a cualquier cosa que se te pueda clavar en el cuerpo, y tampoco me extrañaría que se llamara así a cualquier cosa que se pueda clavar en otra, como es el caso del palillo de los pinchos (a fin de cuentas, de algún sitio habrá tenido que surgir el nombre de "pincho" para la tapa).

Por tanto, no encuentro raro decir que la tapa está pinchada con un "pincho", aunque desde luego nunca diría que me voy a hurgar los dientes con un "pincho" sino con un "palillo".

Acabar diciendo que el *Diccionario de americanismos* no da ningún significado especial para México para la palabra "pincho", y sí una para "palillo" pero hace referencia a un tipo de arbusto.

Comment: tambien he oido decir *pincho* al pendrive (memoria USB)

Comment: @lois6b tienes razón, yo también. Siguiendo la misma lógica: es algo que se puede "pinchar" en otra cosa.

Comment: Coincido completamente, pero ambos somos españoles. A ver si alguien del otro lado del charco aclara si en hispanoamérica si se pueden refererir a un palillo como "pincho".

Comment: @Diego - No sé.  Nunca había visto *pincho*.  Lo que saco del dedo con una aguja esterilizada lo llamo *astilla*.